# How to edit WHMCS files in computer (tpl files)

Tags: html, whmcs

I bought [this template](https://themeforest.net/item/hoskia-multipurpose-hosting-with-whmcs-theme/21574536) but I don't know how to edit its files on my computer. It seems the file extensions are .tpl

How can I edit them like HTML files and then upload them to the server?

Comment: Please use only relevant tags. This question has nothing to do with .NET's Task Parallel Library or any kind of parallelism

Answer (score 0):

Whmcs (a webhost and billing manager software) uses the .tpl files to allow for customisations. There is no way to edit them like html, that I know of.

Tpl files basically need a bit of trial and error in modifying them.

The best way would be to install a trial version of Whmcs or if you have it already installed, perhaps install a second development version (you can apply for a free development license from whmcs).

Then use a txt editor like notepad++ (or another html editor software) to edit the tpl files - then upload to your test site - tweak and repeat as needed... yes, it's not user friendly - but that's whmcs for you.

The [whmcs documentation](https://developers.whmcs.com/) gives a helping hand too.